# What pattern should be used in a java.util.Scanner to fetch the next String identifier?

Tags: java, pattern-matching, java.util.scanner

In a line of text, I have "`*(,identifier1*(identifier2`" and I want to read the identifiers, defined as word characters (`[a-zA-Z_0-9]`).

Which patter should I use? I thought of using:

```
scanner.next( "[\\w]+");
```

but I'm getting the exception `java.util.InputMismatchException`

Comment: What are the characters being used as a delimiter in the text source? The InputMismatchException is saying that Scanner can't match the token to a String.

Comment: The delimiter is anything that is not a letter, a digit or an underscore. And the delimiter may be several characters wide.

Comment: @James, it is a valid regex pattern.

Comment: You're right. Forgot that Java requires double backslashes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Scanner's default delimiter is white spaces, so the first (and only) token in your Scanner object is the entire string `"*(,identifier1*(identifier2"`. That string you're trying to get by calling `next("[\\w]+")`, which causes the exception to be thrown since it does not match your input.

What you're after is more like `findInLine("\\w+")`:

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner("*(,identifier1*(identifier2");
System.out.println(scan.findInLine("\\w+"));
System.out.println(scan.findInLine("\\w+"));
```

which produces:

```
identifier1
identifier2
```

Or if you want to split your input string on one or more non- (ascii) alpha-num-chars (and `_`), try:

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner("*(,identifier1*(identifier2").useDelimiter("\\W+");
while(scan.hasNext()) {
  System.out.println(scan.next());
}
```

which produces the same output as before.

Note that I used the capital `W`, which equals:

```
\W == [^\w] == [^a-zA-Z0-9_]
```

Comment: Your solution `findInLine` works. It seems `Scanner.next( regex)` throws an exception, when it fails to read(!?)

Comment: @John, yes, it throws an exception if the next token in the stream does not match your supplied pattern. If you change your `scanner.next("[\\w]+");` into `scanner.next(".+");` it would match your first token properly (which equals the entire input string).

Comment: +1 for use of `\W` as delimiter. @John: Are you getting an Exception with Bart's code?

Comment: I used this to parse some C style identifiers, one warning though, C allows $ in identifiers so I wasn't able to use \w

Answer (score 1):

Unless there is some reason you have to use a scanner, you could get the String from wherever you wish and then extract the words directly.  Of course this loads all the words into memory at once, whereas with a scanner they're read in one at a time:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> words = extractWords("*(,identifier1*(identifier2");
        for (String word : words)
            System.out.println(word);
    }

    public static List<String> extractWords(String input) {
        List<String> out = new ArrayList<String>();

        Pattern re = Pattern.compile("\\w+");
        Matcher matcher = re.matcher(input);
        while (matcher.find())
            out.add(matcher.group());

        return out;
    }
}
```

Generates the output:

```
identifier1
identifier2
```

Comment: This isn't an option, because I'm reading a large file. But your solution is interesting as well. +1.